# Java: How to parse a String to different specified classes

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to implement a reusable commad scanner for the console. My Command Types are stored in an enum like this and have different parameters:

```
HELP("help", "  * list all commands"),
EXIT("exit", "  * exit program"),
ADDI("addi", "<param1>  <param2>   * simple integer add ",int.class, int.class ),
ADDF("addf", "<param1>  <param2>   * simple float add ",float.class, float.class ),
ECHO("echo", "<param1>  <param2>   * echos param1 string param2 times ",String.class, int.class );
```

In my CommandScanner Class i need a method to parse a String from the CommandLine to the specified class:

```
public Object parseString (String s, Class c) {
        //parse String to the specified Class and return it
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to narrow this down a bit. Which specific example are you having trouble with?  What is your `String s` going to be?

Comment: @matt The `String s` is going to be "12" for example and the `Class c`  "int.class" for example. And then i would expect the method to return an Integer Object with the value of 12.

Comment: I think better than the accepted answer would be to give the enum a `handle Parameters(String...) ` method that each item implements differently.

Comment: Could you add a link to the code or post some of the additional code with your question?  This link shows some guidelines on providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've left it pretty open, but lets pretend that you parse your input into parameters so now you have a String parameter and the class it represents.

If you're using the primative class type I would suggest a switch statement for delegation.

```
String name = c.getName();
switch(name){
    case "int":
        return Integer.valueOf(s);
    case "float":
        return Float.valueOf(s);
    default:
        //grab a constructor that takes a string or 'valueOf' method.
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, thats what i needed. I thought maybe there is a single statement to parse into the class value.

Comment: @Marco yes and no. The primative classes, int.class, byte.class are special and have no declared constructors. The Object wrapper versions, Integer.class and Float.class have constructors, and they have a String argument version *but* the constructors are all deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :)

```
public static Object parseString (String s, Class<?> c) throws NoSuchMethodException, 
                        InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Method valueOf = c.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class);
    valueOf.setAccessible(true);
    return valueOf.invoke(c, s);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try it? I think it is a good idea, and it would work great for Integer.class but not int.class.

Comment: Yes. It will work with classes with valueOf method and not with primitive classes. So instead of int, we should Integer. 
You can add valueOf method to your classes if you want to use it.